# What is wrong with this Linker error in Microsoft Visual?

Tags: c++

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. This is really driving me nuts, as a 1 month C++ novice learner. It's maybe because i'm stupid. Anyway, i get this linker error :

LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open D:\coding\visualstudio\CW_stringsorting\Debug\CW_stringsorting.exe for writing

I am trying too solve an 8 kyu problem from Code Wars and for this to happen, i thought i start with something easier by doing step-by-step algorithms that i think will help me solve the problem.Now, i am just trying to concatenate some strings into 1 single string. Since i didn't study yet very much vectors or strings i supose something basic is wrong with this code, but i can't see what. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


string twoSort(vector<string> s) {

string a;
int size = s.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    a += s[i];
}


return a;
}


int main()
{
string twoSort(vector<string> s);


cout<<twoSort({ "bitcoin", "take", "over", "the", "world", "maybe", "who", "knows", "perhaps" });

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check task manager to make sure `CW_stringsorting.exe` is not currently running.

Comment: Usual reason is the program is still running when you try to recompile it .

Comment: @ChrisMM,@Richard Critten thank you both for answering, but i closed it and opened it again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does that directory exist?

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: CW_stringsorting, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open D:\coding\visualstudio\CW_stringsorting\Debug\CW_stringsorting.exe for writing
1>D:\programs\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(725,5): error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1168.
1>Done building project "CW_stringsorting.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @perj If by "it" you mean Visual Studio, that's not the program you need to stop. If "it" is `CW_stringsorting.exe`, you should not be opening it again.

Comment: D:\coding\visualstudio\CW_stringsorting\Debug\CW_stringsorting.exe --> this exists

D:\programs\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(725,5) --> this exists until D:\programs\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon

Comment: @molbdnilo i looked in the task manager and that executable (CW_stringsorting.exe) is not opened.

Comment: Check virus scanner, including built-in ones. If necessary add an exclude path.

Comment: What is drive D?

Comment: Thank you all for recommandations. It still doesn't work, but i will drop it.

Comment: @stark Drive D is where i do not have installed Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to help as it is probably an environment issue.

Your program does not seem big. You can try the following:

- restart your computer
- create another new project with different name and in different folder in Visual Studio.
- try if compilation of this empty project works (it should).
- copy & paste your program to a new project.
- compilation should work.

It is not an elaborated answer but I'm trying to advice at least something :)

Comment: And the empty project was compiled successfully?

Comment: It worked by copy-pasting into a new project. Thank you very much!